# Repeat cell 'x' number of times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried using/altering other forum's answers and can't seem to get the code right.  I am wanting to repeat entire lines 'x' number of times (x being in column U).  This will be a document that I use over and over again with changing data in the lines, and just need a macro to dictate how many times the line repeats.  I am a total coding novice-- any advise helps!
[image: example of the document attached.]

Comment: What is the exact behavior you need? That as soon as any U cell is modified, that line is copied U-1 times below? What if it's not the last row?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code that shall copy range from A:U and copy is below:

```js
function repeatrow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var repeattime = ss.getRange('U3').getValue();
  ss.getRange('A4:U').clearContent();
  var value = ss.getRange('A3:U3').getValues();
  for (i = 0; i <= repeattime - 1; i++) {
    ss.getRange("A" + (i + 4) + ":U" + (i + 4)).setValues(value);

  };
};
```